# Unusual behavior of scrollbar

Tags: android, xml, textview, scrollbar

I have a problem with scrollbar. I create a TextView in xml and enable vertical scrollbar. I have also define custom thumb thanks to

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/blue"
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@color/white"
```

I run this on Android 4.0.3 and everything wrok fine, but when I am running it on Android 2.3.6 the thumb stretch to parent size ( textview size ) and covert it. What is weird is when I set default scrollbar ( my custom thumb will be removed ) everything work fine. How can I it work fine fith default scrollbar and with custom not?

Answer (score 0):

I replace "@color/blue" to "@drawable/blue", and it's work fine.